# try not to call a helper when recursively inserting nodes to a BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am writing recursion to insert nodes of a BST.
I see many examples online calls a helper, but I am trying not to do so.
However, my code throws error.

It seems like the first number has been added, since the size is 1.
However, the exception seems still regards the root as null.

```
    public void add(Node root, E e) {
        if(root == null) {
            this.root = new Node(e);
            size++;
        }
        else {
            if(e.compareTo((E)this.root) > 0)
                add(this.root.right, e);
            else
                add(this.root.left, e);
        }
    } // add



public class Main {
    public static <E> void main(String[] args){
        BST<Integer> bst = new BST();
        int[] nums = {5, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2};
        for(int num: nums) {
            System.out.printf("size = %d\n",bst.size());
            System.out.printf("root = %d\n",bst.root);
            System.out.printf("num = %d\n",num);        
            bst.add(bst.root, num);  
        }
    }
```

below is the output and the details of error

```
size = 0

root = null

num = 5

size = 1

root = Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != myBST.BST$Node
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4445)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2911)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
    at myBST.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a helper method?

Comment: I just want to challenge myself.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the exception is clear:

```
System.out.printf("root = %d\n",bst.root);
```

'root' has type Node

'%d' demands a numeric argument (or null)

That's why the error message says "IllegalFormatConversionException: d != myBST.BST$Node"

I'd fix that before going any further, so you can see what is really happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Karashi, if this answers your question, you should mark it as accepted.